# Why do some installed windows updates appear in Control Panel but not in Windows Settings?

Tags: windows-10, windows-update, control-panel

Why do some installed windows updates appear in Control Panel but not in Windows Settings?
See the list below.

```
Adobe Reader DC 12/02/21
Security Update for Microsoft Expression Design 4 21/10/20
Microsoft Expression Web Service Pack 21/10/20
Microsoft Silverlight 5.1.50918.0 07/10/20
Security Update for Microsoft Windows KB4601319  12/02/21
Security Update for Microsoft Windows KB4598481 15/01/21
Security Update for Microsoft Windows KB4593175 10/12/20
Security Update for Microsoft Windows KB4586864 12/11/20
Security Update for Flash Player 21/10/20
Security Update for Microsoft Windows KB4577266 21/10/20
```

Comment: So which updates exactly are appearing in Control Panel and not appearing in Windows Update history within Settings?

Comment: I've updated my question since I first posted it. Read my question again for the list of installed updates that don't appear in Settings.

Comment: Only Windows Updates are shown in Windows Update History.  Some of those items are not even Windows Updates

Comment: But some of them are.

Comment: Can you just provide screenshots because I can’t make heads or tails of which updates you are indicating appear in the control panel add/remove and absolutely should not be in Settings Windows Update History

Comment: Here's the screenshots. https://imgur.com/a/u2jIUuM

Comment: I added a follow note in my answer to say that there is an overlap of same updates in both Installed Updates and Settings and also that this difference is disappearing in the next version of Windows . So overall we are in a transition. But to say again, the updates (particularly the KB you posted) is in both place (not in one - not the other).

Answer (score 0):

That may be unique to your machine or to a particular version you have.

I checked my own machines here and KB4601319 only show up in Windows 10 Settings, Update History. Also on all machines none show up in Control Panel.

I think it has been this way for my machines all along, at least as far back as I can reasonably remember.

For Windows 10 Versions from very roughly 2018, and for software compliant with these versions, and for Intel, AMD systems, updates show up in Windows Settings, Updates, Update History.

If a given system would display differently, it would be an anomaly of that system and the software installed on it, and not representative of Windows 10 in general.

**Follow up note:**  There is a section in Programs and Features called **Installed Updates**.  In there, for the newer updates, this list duplicates Windows Settings, Updates, Update History. Same updates for the most current updates.

The Installed Updates section has older updates (older dates) that are not in Settings, Update History.

Neither portrayal has ALL updates installed as that would be a huge list of (IMHO) dubious value.

I think this is just part of the ongoing transition from Control Panel for many functions to Windows Settings.

In fact, in Windows Insider (Windows 10 to come in six months or so) there is only two updates in Control Panel, Installed Updates whereas Settings Update History is much more complete.

So this follow up note is to acknowledge some overlap of the same updates (not either or) which is disappearing as Windows 10 moves ahead. The Settings, Update list is more current and reliable.

[image: Control Panel Installed Updates]

[image: Windows 10 KB4601319]

[Windows 10 KB4601319 article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/february-9-2021-kb4601319-os-builds-19041-804-and-19042-804-87fc8417-4a81-0ebb-5baa-40cfab2fbfde)

Comment: Well that's not the only windows update that doesn't show up in settings. I have multiple ones that show up in control panel but not settings.

Comment: Maybe post a screen shot in your question of such a Control Panel Windows Update.   All I have is Visual C redistributables tied to QuickBooks and none other.

Comment: I've updated my question.

Comment: So I see. What version of Windows (Pro, Home, Education, .... and Build  V20H2, .... ). None of these updates are in Control Panel on any of my machines. Also, Silverlight is long gone.

Comment: Windows 10 20H2, Home edition. Yes I know Silverlight is discontinued lol. It was Windows 10 1909 when I brought the laptop.

Comment: So then it is an anomaly of your particular system, and not the way a Windows 10 system with fully compliant software displays Windows Updates in Settings Update History.